# Does the closed form of combinatorial sum exist?

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to ask you to help me with this problem that I can't solve. Thanks in advance. Any suggestions will be appreciated.
It states :
Find the closed (or approximate) form of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left \lfloor{ \frac{{n \choose k}}{{k+1}}}\right \rfloor$. I don't even know if it has a solution.

Comment: Computing, it seems that for large values of $n$, the logarithm of the expression seems to vary linearly with $n$ (this is just a visual observation, probably of not much help).

Comment: [Apparently not](http://oeis.org/A095718). But we do know that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\displaystyle{n\choose k}}{k+1} ~=~ \frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Find the closed $($or approximate$)$ form of* $~\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{n\choose k}{k+1}\right\rfloor$

The exact values, for the sum starting at $k=0$, can be found on [*OEIS*](http://oeis.org/A095718). There does not appear

to be a closed form. However, we have $~\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n\left\lfloor\frac{n\choose k}{k+1}\right\rfloor~\simeq~\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\displaystyle{n\choose k}}{k+1}~=~\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$